# Shell: Catch user input with cat

Tags: shell, unix, cat

How can I catch input from a shell script that is called with a pipe, without the risk of cat waiting for input forever?

```
echo "hello world" | mysript.sh
```

In the script I try to fetch the input with:

```
input=$(cat)
```

But in some cases `cat` command causes the whole script to timeout, because it waits for input.

Comment: You want to catch input but you don't want to wait for input?

Comment: Input has to end with EOF = ctrl+D.

Comment: Consider using `read` in your script instead. You can read line-by-line, and your shell may support extra tools like timeouts and single-character reads.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want to process data from pipe in shell script, try:

In script:

```
read LINE
echo $LINE
```

In command line:

```
echo "hello world" | ./mysript.sh
```

In this case, `hello world` will be read into `LINE`.

Comment: Try that with anything that contains a globbing pattern, "`/etc/*`" for example (i.e. double-quote `$LINE`).